# How can I do a search and replace in MySQL based on a list of words in a table?

Tags: mysql, regex-lookarounds, mysql-5.6

I have a field company_name that uses a list of abbreviations.  I need to expand the abbreviations to their full name, like SVCS to SERVICES, but also only match the abbreviations if they are at the beginning, end, or with a non-word character adjacent.  I put all the abbreviations in a table name_abbr like so:

```
abbr | full
--------------
SVCS | SERVICES
CONS | CONSULTING
TX   | TEXAS
BROS | BROTHERS
```

I also created a function to loop through the abbreviations table like so:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `expand_abbr`( str VARCHAR(255) ) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    #Test:  select expand_abbr('JOHN SVCS, LTD'); #'JOHN SERVICES, LTD'
    #Test:  select expand_abbr('TX BROS LLC'); #'TEXAS BROTHERS LLC'
    declare ret varchar(255);

    declare abbr varchar(50);
    declare abbr_full varchar(50);

    declare done integer default 0;
    declare abbr_cursor cursor for
        select * from name_abbr;
    declare continue handler for not found set done = 1;

    set ret = str;

    OPEN abbr_cursor;

    get_abbr:  LOOP
        FETCH abbr_cursor INTO abbr, abbr_full;

        if done = 1 then
            leave get_abbr;
        end if;

        set ret = ???
    end loop get_abbr;

    close abbr_cursor;

    RETURN ret; 
END
```

I'm stuck on what to use at ??? since I believe this would require a lookahead and lookbehind, but those aren't supported in POSIX regex.  Thanks for the help.